# Nginx takes too long to send the network response using Django with Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, webserver, gunicorn

I'm developing a web application with Django, and so far everything seems ok, but I'm having a big problem with my server response, usually the first time I want to enter it takes around 20 to 40 seconds to get the response back from the server.

I'm using a Linode linux virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04, is a very cheap plan just for now with only one core CPU, 2GB of ram and 50Gb of SSD storage, however as I'm the only one accessing the website I feel it is not correct that it takes so long to response (It just happen every time I restart nginx or gunicorn, or after some time of inactivity, after it respond it start to work with a normal speed).

I made a performance record with chrome dev tools and these were my results:

[Network result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2751.png)

As you can see the network request took 22 seconds, and if I check the main thread I can see that chrome detects that time as idle, and the real time it takes the server to process the view is only a few milliseconds.

[Chrome results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzGcj.png)

I also have my server with an SSL certificate, the config for nginx is the following:

```sh
upstream rienpaAdmin {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /correct/path/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /correct/path/certificate.key;
    server_name lodugo.com www.lodugo.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/www/rienpaAdmin/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/rienpaAdmin/nginx-error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/rienpaAdmin;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name lodugo.com www.lodugo.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

And I have a gunicorn service and socket like this:

socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/rienpaAdmin
ExecStart=/var/www/rienpaAdmin/adminPython/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --threads 1 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          rienpaAdmin.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Anyone can give me a good explaination why this is happening?, I can upgrade my Linode server but I really feel that my current setup for just one user should respond very fast as it does after the first request, I have several days reading other questions but none of them really helped me to figure this out.

Just in case, I'm using Django 3.0 with a postgreSQL database

EDIT:

One of the answers says that I have two A records to different IPs, here is a screenshot of my DNS configuration of my NameCheap domain

[image: here]

Comment: what makes you think its your  compute  or  nginx ? How  does this profiling compare to your local django request? Also, what is the distance between you and the linode server? Assuming you're in Australia and the server is in NYC thats quite a trip!

Comment: btw, if your site is "lodugo.com" i got a sub 70 ms response time which is SUPER fast even though it just says "hola"

Comment: In my development server the request doesn't take more than 200ms, and the url I'm profiling usually never pass the 100ms, my linode server is on Texas, and I'm on Chile, if I do a ping command the packets vary from 90ms to 130ms, I think that's ok, and yes, the site is "lodugo.com", but on the very first request I cannot make it to respond as it should, sometimes it takes even 1 minute to get that "Hola" back, but after that it's very fast

Comment: Yeah so the distance from Texas to Chile is very big. So that will always add some delay. If you want to speed it up once you are all setup, use a CDN like CloudFlare to help distribute that static files and help speed up some requests from far away places

Comment: Also, if this is a new site with a new server and name etc, the DNS's servers around the world need to update their records and include your site. So until the rest of the network picks up there will be some slowness

Comment: But it is really normal to have to wait those 20 seconds for just a text response?, the server is already 1 month old, and also, after the first request everythiing start to work pretty well, I just feel something might be wrong

Comment: I really don't know how to phrase this into words but it's along the lines of:
The server goes to sleep when it doesn't have any requests. However once you do send the first request, the server starts actively listening for more. It's working the way it's supposed to, there's absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry but if my visits are low and then after a couple hours someone access my website I don't want that person to wait about 20 seconds to 1 minute to get the response from the server in the very first request, I have never seen that behaviour over any other website. In any case, there is a way to keep it always on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you realise there are 2 A records for your domain name?

```
$ dig lodugo.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
lodugo.com.             1308    IN      A       192.64.119.241
lodugo.com.             1308    IN      A       45.56.114.74
```

DNS servers will respond with each IP address in turn.  I suspect that only one of the addresses is correct so there is a 50% chance of getting a bad address that will eventually timeout, and then may retry.

This fits with what I have seen - Often taking a long time to connect, but once you hit the right address that will give fast responses until the DNS record reaches the end of it's TTL.  At that point you have a 50% chance again.

Comment: Wow, that's sounds about right, just one of those IP addresses is the correct one!, but I'm using a NameCheap domain, I truly have two A records, but both point to 45.56.114.74, can you give me a hand on where is the other IP set?, I will update the question with my DNS configuration

Comment: Forget that, you were right, after you pointed that out I solved my problem after a little of investigation, thank you so much!

Comment: Great.  I'm sure the 2 separate A records for @ (= bare domain) and www are fine.  Was the URL redirect record causing the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I deleted the A record for the www and the URL redirect, then, created a new URL redirect from www to https://lodugo.com, and after that the dig command reported only one IP address and everything started to work pretty well out of the box

Comment: Thanks man. I forgot I reinstalled my server and never changed the IP in the DNS records to begin with!